# "any" function gives warning message

Tags: r

I was typing some code in R and noticed that

```
> any(range(2.0,3.0))
```

gave me the following:

```
Warning message:
In any(range(2, 3)) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical
```

I looked up the help function by typing `? any` and got the following:

```
Coercion of types other than integer (raw, double, complex, character, list) gives a warning as this is often unintentional.
```

So I typed `any(range(2,3))` and still got the same warning. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Why* are you using the function like that? As the documentation says, a coercion happens because `any` is called on *logical* values (`TRUE`, `FALSE`). It makes little sense on other values.

As for why you’re still getting the error: in R, `2` and `3` are numerics, not integers. You could use `any(range(2L, 3L))` but this isn’t really any more meaningful. In fact, R should warn here as well.

Comment: I want to test whether any number is negative.

Comment: @wwl But `any` doesn’t do that (directly). What made you think so?

Comment: Oops, my code should have been any(range(2,3) < 0). Sorry!

Comment: @wwl So the warning fulfilled its purpose. ;-)